# Postgres - retrieve last child hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

Suppose I have following DDL:

```
CREATE table foo(id integer primary key, parent_id integer);
insert into foo values(1,null);
insert into foo values(2,null);
insert into foo values(3,2);
insert into foo values(4,2);
insert into foo values(5,4);
```

I need to retrieve only last level of the hierarchy, and one item can have multiple childs, this way I need to retrieve only rows with id `1`,`3`, and `5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use not exists

```
 Select *
 From foo f1
 Where not exists (
    Select 1
    From foo f2
    Where f2.parent_id = f1.id
 )
```